# Can I add return when I use Elvis operation in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have read Elvis Operator  at http://mings.in/2017/03/12/Kotlin-Null-Safety.html

The Code A and Code C are OK, but Code B is error ("Type mismatch: inferred type is Int but Unit was expected" ), why?

**Code A**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)  

      val b: String?  = "hello"
      val l = b?.length ?: -1
 }
```

**Code B**

```
   override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

      val b: String?  = "hello"
      val l = b?.length ?: return -1

    }
```

**Code C**

```
 fun getLength(b: String?): Int {
        val l = b?.length ?: return -1       
        return l
    }
```

BTW, BakaWaii told me "Code A is ok because -1 is an expression which denotes a value, so that it can be assigned to l. But in code B, return -1 is an expression which returns from a function."

I can't understand that "in code B, return -1 is an expression which returns from a function". I think that "return -1 " will return -1, why does the app occur "Type mismatch: inferred type is Int but Unit was expected" ?

**And more:**

Code C just like Code B, I don't know why it's OK !!!!

Comment: What happens when you try to compile or run it? That will give you your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Difference between `Code A` and `Code B` that first one set `-1` to your variable (now it is `l`), and second one set `-1` as result of function work. And `Type mismatch` error message says that function should not return any value (or return `Unit`) but you are trying to return int - so it is not Elvis operator syntax error.

Then if you place your `Code B` in some `Int` function (like you did it in `Code C`) there would not be any errors.

**Example**

If you want to "convert" `Int` to `StringBuilder` you can do it like following:

```
fun toStringBuilder(i: Int?): StringBuilder {
    val result = i?.toString() ?: ""
    return StringBuilder(result)
}
```

Guess there is no questions.

Second example is absolutelly correct too.

```
fun toStringBuilder(i: Int?): StringBuilder {
    val result = i?.toString() ?: return StringBuilder()
    return StringBuilder(result)
}
```

If parameter value is `null` function will not reach second line because it would return at first.

And third example whould generate error (like your `Code B`).

```
fun toStringBuilder(i: Int?): StringBuilder {
    val result = i?.toString() ?: return ""
    return StringBuilder(result)
}
```

Again there is no error in syntax. Elvis operator is correct. Error is because you are trying to return `String` to function that declared as returning `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Thanks! it's hard to understand Code B, could you write down a equivalence code of Code B for me ?

Comment: @HelloCW Added example to my answer.

Comment: Thanks! Now I see completely. Before I think "return -1" will assign -1 to var l in Code B, in fact it's to assign -1 to function  onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?), and Android studio doesn't give more details error message.

Answer (score 8):

From [Kotlin's doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#elvis-operator):

> If the expression to the left of `?:` is not null, the elvis operator returns it, otherwise it returns the expression to the right. Note that, since `throw` and `return` are expressions in Kotlin, they can also be used on the right hand side of the elvis operator.

and [also](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#returns-and-jumps),

> `return`. By default returns from the nearest enclosing function or anonymous function.

So, the answer is yes, as long as the return type of the enclosing function matches with the return value, for example:

```
fun getLength(b: String?): Int {
    val l = b?.length ?: return -1    //return an `Int`
    //if return -1, the code below will not execute
    return l
}
```

Note that code A and code B are different in control flow. If you are trying to assign an alternative/default value when the left-hand side value is null, code A will be the best approach.

Comment: Thanks! but I get the error  "Type mismatch: inferred type is Int but Unit was expected" when I use Code B

Comment: The return type of the enclosing function should be match with the return value. See the above example. The return type of `getLength()` is `Int` and the return value is `-1`. The `return` here returns from the nearest enclosing function but not assigning a value to `l`.

Comment: But Why is Code A  OK ?

Comment: and more val l = b?.length ?: {return -1} is not OK

Comment: Code A is ok because `-1` is an expression which denotes a value, so that it can be assigned to `l`. But in code B, `return -1` is an expression which returns from a function.

Comment: Don't mix up the elvis operator with `if-else`. When you write `{return -1}` after `?:`, it denotes a function type and `return` is not allowed here. You should use `run` if you need to run a block of code using elvis operator. Like: `val l = b?.length ?: run { return -1 }` or `val l = b?.length ?: run { return@run -1 }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154850/discussion-between-bakawaii-and-hellocw).

Comment: To BakaWaii, could you have a look at my question which I have made some update ? Thanks!